# get array value when comparing it

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays `fruit`

```js
      Array(
        [0]=>'Apple',
        [1]=>'orange',
        [2]=>'guava'
        )
```

and second array is `Allfruits`

```js
    Array(
    [0]=>'Strawberry',
    [1]=>'Manggo',
    [2]=>'durian',
    [3]=>'Apple',
    [4]=>'guava')
```

And then an empty array call `$data`

My question is how to insert members of `Allfruits` when it not exists in `fruit` array?

So with this example, i want the result is all fruit except Apple and guava inside data array any sugestion?

Comment: ```array_diff```

Comment: What result do you need? @Bayu Zangetsu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing that

```
$items_to_add = array_diff($array_fruit, $array_all_fruit);

$exclude_existing = array_diff($array_all_fruit, $array_fruit);

$new_array = array_merge($items_to_add, $exclude_existing);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using below function, you can merge 2arrays without duplicate

```
function mergeArrayIfNotExist($childArray, $parentArray) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($childArray), $i++) {
        if (!in_array($childArray[$i], $parentArray)) {
            array_push($parentArray, $childArray[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $parentArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a loop and search the value in the **$data** array. If it is in the array then get it's index by using **array_search** function and unset the value, otherwise add the value in  **$data** array. Finally re-index the array if you need.

```
$check = ['Apple','orange','guava'];
$data = ['Strawberry','Manggo','durian','Apple','guava'];

foreach ($check as $key => $value) {
    if(( $index = array_search( $value, $data )) !== false ){
        unset( $data[$index] ); 
    }else{
        $data[] = $value;
    }
}
$data = array_values( $data ); //for re-indexing the array
```